# Python project not building in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, sublimetext3

I am using Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10 to write simple programs regarding user input. I was using IDLE to write the programs. They mostly rely on the `input()` function to retrieve input from the user. Midway, I decided to switch to Sublime Text. Upon building my program the Sublime Text input box was empty except for the line `[Finished in 85ms]` with no output from the program whatsoever.

Here is the program:

class Order:

```
'''Order class for both burgers and pizzas'''

def __init__(self, food = 'burger'):
    self.food = (food.lower)

def order_burger(self, drink, *burger):
    
    self.drink = drink
    self.burger = burger

    for burgers in burger:

        cost += (burger.get(burger))
```

while True:

```
cost = 0

name = input("Hello, what is your name?\n:")
    
(name) = Order(input(f"Hello {name}, what kind of food would you like? (Burger / Pizza)\n:"))

(name).order_burger(input(f"This is the list of available ingredients: \n{available_burger_ingredients} \nWhat ingredients would you like to have in your burger?\n:").split(),
                    input(f"This is the list of available drinks: \n{available_drinks} \n What would you like to drink? (Choose one only)\n:")
                    )
```

I then experimented using a simple program (`print("hello world")`) to test whether the program was faulty or not, but it was still not printing anything. Do I need to rewrite the program in Sublime Text rather than IDLE?

Comment: And you're looking at the right output tab/view? (i.e. you looked up how to use Sublime Text 3 for Python, and read through where input/output gets read from and written to?)

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't show up even if I scroll up.